# Firestore rules don't seem to work ERROR Error: Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, firebase-security

I have a pretty simple query here (Using AngularFire to interact with firestore):

```
initializeEventFeed(): void {
    this.eventCollection = this.db.collection('Events', ref => ref.orderBy('date'));
    this.eventCollection$ = this.eventCollection.valueChanges();
  }
```

That works fine when my rules are set as:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

But if I make the rules any bit more complex, then I'll get the insufficient permissions error:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /Events/{event} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Or something more practicial (which I would like):

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /Events/{event} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow write: if request.auth.token.email == "authedWriteUser@gmail.com";
    }
  }
}
```

What's really weird is even just flatout setting them to true gives the permission errors still:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /Events/{event} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to reproduce your problem, but it works fine for me.

My data:

[image: Data structure in Firestore console]

My rules:

```
match /48868872/{event} {
  allow read
}
```

My code:

```
var query = firebase.firestore().collection("/48868872").orderBy('date');

query.get().then((snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach((document) => { console.log(document.id); })
}).catch(console.error);
```

Live link: https://jsbin.com/kataduw/edit?html,js,console

Comment: The only difference I can think of is that your bin is just raw js, whereas I'm using angularfire to interact with firestore.  (I'll edit my question to mention I'm using it, didn't think it would be relevant).

Comment: I don't think AngularFire would make a difference here. Can you reproduce the problem in a jsbin like what I've done, so that we have both a working and  non-working sample to look at?

Comment: With my jsbin it seems to work as expected.  If I add a rule to only allow a certain email to read it, I'll get the `insufficient permissions` error as expected.

I'm wondering now if there's something to do with my query, if the request.auth isn't being sent along with it?  I'm just using google oauth in my app so I figured angularfire/firestore was handling that for me.  Do you know if there are any logs in the firebase console that gives a clearer error?

Comment: That could be, for example if you send the query before the user has been authenticated properly. It's impossible to say from the code you shared so far though.

Comment: The user has definitely been authenticated at this point.  When testing the rules I was refreshing my app with the authed user logged in already.  Every page on my app is protected by a router guard that checks for authentication, otherwise they're redirected to login.

Comment: Would auth have to be re-established on every page load?  Do I have to wait for the authed user on every load before doing any firestore operations?

Comment: Is your query trying to return all documents in the collection or are you filtering it by the user ID?  Cloud Firestore rules do not provide filtering.  If your read permission require you to have a particular field set to the user ID, you need to have a `.where` filter to reflect that.